# Finding list of dominators of a single node (with respect to a single entry node)?

Tags: performance

There are many resources on the Internet for Tarjan's algorithm that finds the dominator tree with respect to a single entry node. However, I just want to find the dominators of a single node of the tree.

Is there an easier way to do this than using Tarjan's O(m log n) time algorithm which computes the dominator tree and then we iterate through the tree to find the dominators of a particular node? I want to do this quicker than O(m log n) time for the single node case.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know of any *existing* algorithm that does this, I can think of one.

Let the entry node be the *root*, and the **t**arget node (to find its dominators) be *t*. Make a DFS tree rooted at *root*.

Now note that the set of dominators of *t* are a subset of the ancestors of *t* on the DFS tree, and only forward edges and cross edges can "avoid" those nodes on a path from *root* to *t*. So:

- For each node *node*, let *f(node)* be the highest ancestor of *t* that can reach *node* without walking on any other ancestors of *t*. This can be computed in linear time with memoization.
- For each cross edge *x → y* where *y* is an ancestor of *t*, all nodes that are strict sucessors of *f(x)* and strict ancestors of *y* are not dominators of *t*. (because the path *root → ... → f(x) → ... → x → y → ... → t* does not path through those nodes)

The algorithm (*O(n+m)*) would be:

- Make a DFS tree rooted as *root*.
- Mark all ancestors of *t* as "possible candidates".
- Compute *f(node)* for all nodes.
- For each *x → y* as described above, mark the list of nodes in the path *f(x) → ... → y* (excluding endpoints) as "cannot be dominators" in *O(1)* time using summed table. <sub>(similar to summed area table but in 1D)</sub>
- The remaining candidates are dominators.

Not sure if this is easier.